# AWS S3 uploading 0 B file - node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to AWS S3 using `[putObject][1]` but it results in files of 0 byte size.

I do get successful response back from the putObject call.

**Node.js code:**

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3();

module.exports = {
  upload: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Going to upload");
    console.log(req.files);
    let uploadFile = req.files.file;
    const s3PutParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: uploadFile.name,
      Body: uploadFile.data,
      ACL: "public-read"
    };

    const s3GetParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: uploadFile.name
    };

    console.log(s3PutParams);
    s3.putObject(s3PutParams, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Response is", response);
        var url = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", s3GetParams);
        console.log("The URL is", url);
        res.json({
          returnedUrl: url,
          publicUrl: `https://${process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${uploadFile.name}`
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

**Testing through POSTMAN:**
[image]

**Backend Console log**
[image]

Can anyone help me in figuring out what is wrong?

***EDIT on 11/20:***
@EmmanuelNK helped in spotting the fact that `Buffer.byteLength(req.files.file.data)` is 0. He had the below questions:

> Are you trying to write the whole buffer into memory or are you trying to stream it to s3?

Sorry if the answer is not to the point, still getting my feet wet.
Basically I want to upload an image to S3 and then later use that URL to show it on a webpage. In other words like a photobucket

> how you are using upload

For now I am just testing my backend code (posted in the question) using postman. Once I get that going, will have a file upload form on the front end calling this route.

Is that helpful? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So its 0 bytes in S3 bucket? what about the buffer itself? I know `size` property  shows `64476` but what about `Buffer.byteLength(req.files.file.data)` ? what does it show when you log it?

Comment: @EmmanuelNK It shows 0 when i log `Buffer.byteLength(req.files.file.data)`
And yes, its 0 bytes in S3 bucket.

Comment: Well that's the problem right there. Your buffer is empty. There is no data. So the issue likely lies with your upload code. Are you trying to write the whole buffer into memory or are you trying to stream it to s3? plaease update your question with how you are using upload or where its being used.

Comment: @EmmanuelNK I have updated the question

Comment: What middleware are you using for file upload? Is it `express-fileupload` or something else? Also, can you please show us code you wrote for the middleware setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) as the file uploading middleware, and you've set the `useTempFiles` option to true, keep in mind that your data file buffer will be empty (check [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload#usage)), which correlates to the issue you're facing. To get around this, simply read the temp. file once more to get the intended file buffer.

```
import fs from 'fs';
// OR
const fs = require('fs');

// in your route
let uploadFile = req.files.file;
// THIS
fs.readFile(uploadedFile.tempFilePath, (err, uploadedData) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    const s3PutParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: uploadFile.name,
        Body: uploadData, // <--- THIS
        ACL: "public-read"
    };

    const s3GetParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: uploadFile.name
    };

    console.log(s3PutParams);
    s3.putObject(s3PutParams, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log("Response is", response);
            var url = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", s3GetParams);
            console.log("The URL is", url);
            res.json({
                returnedUrl: url,
                publicUrl: `https://${process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${uploadFile.name}`
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be old but I just had this issue. If you are going to upload directly to S3, set temp to false.

```
app.use(fileUpload({
  useTempFiles : false,
  tempFileDir : '/tmp/',
  debug:true
}));
```